# How to change a value in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm currently working on a school project where I am making a music archive where I am supposed to list different audiotracks, mediums etc. I am using a jTable to do this, but I am supposed to be able to change information of an audiotrack or medium that is already created, title, artist etc.
So my question is, how can I use jTable to directly change information about an object? I use String to hold the title and artist etc.
This is the first time I am using jTable and the first time I am making a GUI, so any tips would help a lot.

Comment: You will need to be clearer about what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried so far...

Comment: Okay, I'm using a jTable to list information about for example a musictrack, with the tracks title, artist, name of the CD etc.
What I want to do, is that when I change the value of for example the title in the jTable, I want the new value to be automatically updated in the musictrack. 
So I have a class named "Music" with a String containing the title, but I don't know how to automatically update that String when changing the value in the table.
Hope this explains my problem better :)

Comment: "This is the first time I am using jTable". Then read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: In particular, `JTable` provides a default editor for any cell that `isCellEditable()`. What's not working?

Comment: Well, I made it work using if- and else-sentences in a "property change"-event, but I'm not sure about how good the design is. 
When I tried to Google it for help, I found a lot of different examples, for example that you can use a TableModelListener, but I'm not currently using any listeners.